How to get from the forward Fourier transform to the inverse Fourier transform
I want to find out the steps and intuition into how we come up with the Inverse Fourier transform. I can't just accept it as is, I want to find the complete derivation from the forward to the inverse. Most solutions I found was just proving that the inverse Fourier transform is true, but proving already assumes an existing solution.
Formally, from the forward Fourier transform which is in the form
$$
f(n) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-2\pi nit}dt
$$
How can we get the inverse which is
$$
f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(n)e^{2\pi nit}dn
$$
Note that I wish to see the complete thinking invlove, not the proof why this is true but the steps that resulted it.

For your definition of the Fourier transform, the $\frac{1}{2 \pi}$ scaling factor on the inverse Fourier transform is incorrect and should be removed.

I'm not sure if I completely understand what you are asking, but here is some intuition that might be useful.
$f\left(n\right)$ is the coefficient of the complex exponential function $e^{-2 \pi i n t}$ which has frequency $n.$  The forward Fourier transform gives us the coefficients as a function of frequency for all the complex exponentials that we are using to represent the original function $f\left(t\right).$  This is basically an inner product of $f\left(t\right)$ with each complex exponential of different frequencies.
To reconstruct $f\left(t\right)$ from the individual complex exponentials, we have to compute the integral of them, weighted by $f\left(n\right)$ which is applied to each complex exponential as a function of frequency.  This reconstruction is the inverse Fourier transform.

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a nice function. The
Fourier transform wishes to express $f$ in terms of the frequency ``basis''
functions $\{ e^{i \xi x} : \xi \in \mathbb{C} \}$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
  f (x) & = & \int \hat{f} (\xi) e^{i \xi x} d \xi .
\end{eqnarray*}
Assume such an expansion exists. How can we solve for $\hat{f}$? The usual
method is to investigate the inner product of $f$ with a basis function $e^{i
\omega x}$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int f (x) e^{- i \omega x} dx & = & \int \int \hat{f} (\xi) e^{i \xi x}
  e^{- i \omega x} d \xi dx\\
  & = & \int \int \hat{f} (\xi) e^{i (\xi - \omega) x} d \xi dx.
\end{eqnarray*}
Let's try interchanging integrals:
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int \int \hat{f} (\xi) e^{i (\xi - \omega) x} d \xi dx & =? & \int
  \hat{f} (\xi)  \int e^{i (\xi - \omega) x} dxd \xi .
\end{eqnarray*}
The inner integral is not absolutely convergent, so interchanging doesn't
work. However, we can throw in a convergence factor to make it convergent. Let
$\varphi$ be a nice function with $\varphi(0) = 1$. Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int \int \hat{f} (\xi) e^{i (\xi - \omega) x} d \xi dx & = &
  \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \int \int \hat{f} (\xi) \varphi
  (\varepsilon x) e^{i (\xi - \omega) x} d \xi dx.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now Fubini's theorem justifies
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int \int \hat{f} (\xi) \varphi (\varepsilon x) e^{i (\xi - \omega) x} d \xi
  dx & = & \int \hat{f} (\xi)  \int \varphi (\varepsilon x) e^{i (\xi -
  \omega) x} dxd \xi\\
  & = & \int \hat{f} (\xi)  \int \varepsilon^{- 1} \varphi (y) e^{i
  \frac{(\xi - \omega)}{\varepsilon} y} dyd \xi\\
  & = & \int \hat{f} (\xi) \varepsilon^{- 1}  \tilde{\varphi} \left(
  \frac{\xi - \omega}{\varepsilon} \right) d \xi\\
  & = & \int \hat{f} (\xi + \omega) \varepsilon^{- 1}  \tilde{\varphi} \left(
  \frac{\xi}{\varepsilon} \right) d \xi\\
  & = & \int \hat{f} (\varepsilon v + \omega)  \tilde{\varphi} (v) dv\\
  & \rightarrow & \hat{f} (\omega)  \int \tilde{\varphi} (v) dv.
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus we have shown that
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int f (x) e^{- i \omega x} dx & = & \hat{f} (\omega)  \int \tilde{\varphi}
  (v) dv.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \hat{f} (\omega) & = & \left( \int \tilde{\varphi} (v) dv \right)^{- 1} 
  \int f (x) e^{- i \omega x} dx.
\end{eqnarray*}
Notice $\varphi$ was arbitrary, so we can pick whatever $\varphi$ we want to
evlauate $\int \tilde{\varphi} (v) dv$, that is, this integral is independent
of $\varphi$! Using $\varphi = e^{- | \xi |}$ makes things pretty easy, and
you can find $\int \tilde{\varphi} (v) dv = 2 \pi$. Hence
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \hat{f} (\omega) & = & \frac{1}{2 \pi}  \int f (x) e^{- i \omega x} dx.
\end{eqnarray*}
